# Can anyone help explain this "Western Hemisphere brunch banter" in the TV series, The Good Place?

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes, culture

Below is from the TV series, The Good Place.

> Michael: I've been working on my Western Hemisphere brunch banter.
>
> That *New Yorker* article was crazy.
>
> You haven't seen *Hamilton*?
>
> Hey, did you hear about Stephanie?

Michael is a demon in a human body, now (pretending to be) trying to learn about human lives.

I think he said Western Hemisphere "brunch" banter because he could share those jokes about western culture over brunch table or something, and *New Yorker* is a newspaper and Hamilton is a musical(?) 
(Have I guessed right so far?)

But I'm not sure about what Stephanie is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each of Micheal's lines is an example of something you might hear at an stereotypical upscale Western brunch. I'll explain each a bit more fully:

"New Yorker" is a weekly magazine (not a newspaper) known for its long-form, in-depth articles. It has a good reputation, but there is a well-known joke that everyone *pretends* to read all the long articles because they want to be known as smart, but few people actually do.

As you suggest, "Hamilton" is a popular Broadway musical. The joke here is that it is so popular that it is notoriously difficult to get tickets (they are regularly sold out *a year in advance*). So asking someone why *they* haven't seen it is a roundabout way of *bragging that you have*.

"Did you hear about Stephanie?", though, isn't a reference to any *specific* person named Stephanie; it's a joke about a *common type of inter-personal gossip*.

I can't confirm this, but it *might* even be a reference to a specific gossip-related meme, where the person who *starts* the rumor about Stephanie then has to feign surprise when a friend repeats it:

[image: a picture of a squirrel looking surprised with the text "Did you hear about Stephanie? / Me:"]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed explanations ;) I would have given you 5 upvotes if i could